# Unable to reach the database server using Prisma, Docker and NestJS

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs, prisma

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHTA143_b-s&t=1623s) on NestJS and it uses Docker to deploy the database (locally). I'm totally new with Docker by the way.

As an ORM, it uses Prisma.

My Docker container launches, "ready to accept connections", but when I do `npx prisma migrate dev`, it returns ->

> Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5434`
> Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5434`.

Here's the DATABASE_URL situated in a .env file (I added the connect_timeout after some searches on internet but it didn't solve the problem) :

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:123@localhost:5434/nest?schema=public?connect_timeout=300"
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml :
[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKSlU.png)

Comment: Is the database running in a container or directly on the host?  The application?  Compose normally runs off a YAML file and not a PNG file; can you [edit] the question to include the actual text of the `docker-compose.yml` directly in the question, not a link to a screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The postgres default port is 5432, not 5431. Try to change it in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

I am following the same tutorial. I had this error as well.
I fixed it by simply deleting the migrations folder inside the prisma folder and then run `npx prisma migrate dev` again.

1. Delete the `migrations` folder inside the `prisma` folder
2. run `npx prisma migrate dev`

What I noticed is that, the error is caused by this command

`db:dev:rm": "docker compose rm dev-db -s -f -v` in your `package.json`

I don't know why though but you may need to avoid using it.

I hope this is helpful.